# Execute a file using PHP exec

Tags: php, windows, exec, shell-exec

I am trying to execute a PHP script by calling `exec()`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
exec("php file.php");
```

I am running on a Windows VPS.  How can I determine what the problem is?

Comment: I've got a better idea. Do this: `require_once 'file.php';`

Comment: Are you trying to execute that file in a new context?  If not, follow Asaph's suggestion.

Comment: i cant use require. I need to use exec()

Comment: *why* can't you use `require()`?

Comment: i need to run it thru command prompt/terminal

Comment: @Asaph Maybe the script NEEDS to be run on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You must have php.exe in your classpath, otherwise, you will get an error. If you just want to include the file do :

```
<?php
    require_once("file.php");
?>
```

If you realy want to use the exec function, you must give the full PHP path and the full path of your file.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Just check that php is a environmental variable. And if not [add it](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/)
- Is the file you are trying to execute in the same directory as your script is ? Assume entering the full path of the file

Comment: Also check if php.ini has exec permission.

Answer (score 0):

The `exec` function is very easy to use, but you have to specify the absolute path for you script and an optional variable to be filled with every line of output from the command, for example:

```
exec("php /var/www/my_script.php", $arr);
```

So, if something is wrong you can do `print_r($arr)` and check the result.